# Reading 13 bands (Sentinel 2A) .tif image in cv::Mat (opencv C++)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, c++, opencv

I want to read 13 bands of a .tif image in separate `cv::Mat` objects for processing. I have tried reading it with opencv `imread()` function but it fails to load it. Also, I have used libtiff but I am unable to figure out how to get these 13 bands of images out of it in C++ for processing using opencv.

Comment: not really an answer, but did you look at the OTB library (which include openCV and GDAL) ?